# Altering unique fields of inherited Django model

Tags: python, django

In Django, I'm trying to create a base model that can be used to track the different version of some other model's data in a transparent way. Something like:

```
class Warehouse(models.Model):

    version_number = models.IntegerField()
    objects = CustomModelManagerFilteringOnVersionNumber()

    class Meta:
        abstract=True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # handling here version number incrementation
        # never overwrite data but create separate records,
        # don't delete but mark as deleted, etc.
        pass

class SomeData(Warehouse):
    id = models.IntegerField( primary_key=True )
    name = models.CharField(unique=True)
```

The problem I have is that `SomeData.name` is actually not unique, the tuple `('version_number', 'name' )` is.

I know I can use the `Meta` class in `SomeData` with `unique_together` but I was wondering whether this could be done in a more transparent way. That is, dynamically modifying/creating this `unique_together` field.

Final note: maybe handling this with model inheritance is not the correct approach but it looked pretty appealing to me if I can handle this field uniqueness problem.

**EDIT:** Obviously the word 'dynamic' in this context is misleading. I do want the uniqueness to be preserved at the database level. The idea is to have different version of the data.

A give here a small example with the above model (assuming an abstract model inheritance, so that everything is in the same table):

The database could contain:

```
version_number | id | name  | #comment
0              | 1  | bob   | first insert
0              | 2  | nicky | first insert
1              | 1  | bobby | bob changed is name on day x.y.z
0              | 3  | malcom| first insert
1              | 3  | malco | name change
2              | 3  | momo  | again...
```

and my custom model manager would filter the data (taking the max on version number for every unique id) so that:
    SomeData.objects.all()
would return

```
id | name
1  | bobby
2  | nicky
3  | momo
```

and would also offer others method that can return data as in version n-1.

Obviously I will use a timestamp instead of a version number so that I can retrieve the data at a given date but the principle remains the same.

Now the problem is that when I do 
    ./manage.py makemigrations 
with the models above, it will enforce uniqueness on *SomeData.name* and on *SomeData.id* when what I need is uniqueness on *('SomeData.id','version_number')* and *('SomeData.name', 'version_number')*. Explicitly, I need to append some fields from the base models into the fields of the inherited models declared as unique in the db and this any times the *manage.py* command is run and/or the production server runs.

Comment: I read it few times and still can get the issue, could you add code examples ?

Comment: You want each field in your model to have this unique_together filter? Keep in mind this is enforced at the db level.

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I ended subclassing the ModelBase from django.db.models.base so that I can insert into 'unique_together' any fields declared as unique. Here is my current code. It does not yet implements the manager and save methods but the db uniqueness constraints are handled correctly.

```
from django.db.models.options import normalize_together
from django.db.models.base import ModelBase
from django.db.models.fields import Field

class WarehouseManager( models.Manager ):
    def get_queryset( self ):
        """Default queryset is filtered to reflect the current status of the db."""

        qs = super( WarehouseManager, self ).\
             get_queryset().\
             filter( wh_version = 0 )

class WarehouseModel( models.Model ):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    class __metaclass__(ModelBase):
        def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
            super_new = ModelBase.__new__

            meta = attrs.get( 'Meta', None )
            try:
                if attrs['Meta'].abstract == True:
                    return super_new(cls, name, bases, attrs )
            except:
                pass

            if meta is not None:
                ut = getattr( meta, 'unique_together', () )
                ut = normalize_together( ut )
                attrs['Meta'].unique_together = tuple( k+('wh_version',) for k in ut )

            unique_togethers = ()
            for fname,f in attrs.items():
                if fname.startswith( 'wh_' ) or not isinstance( f, Field ):
                    continue

                if f.primary_key:
                    if not isinstance( f, models.AutoField ):
                        raise AttributeError( "Warehouse inherited models cannot "
                                "define a primary_key=True field which is not an "
                                "django.db.models.AutoField. Use unique=True instead." )
                    continue

                if f.unique:
                    f._unique = False
                    unique_togethers += ( (fname,'wh_version'), )

            if unique_togethers:
                if 'Meta' in attrs:
                    attrs['Meta'].unique_together += unique_togethers
                else:
                    class DummyMeta: pass
                    attrs['Meta'] = DummyMeta
                    attrs['Meta'].unique_together = unique_togethers

            return super_new(cls, name, bases, attrs )

    wh_date = models.DateTimeField(
        editable=False,
        auto_now=True,
        db_index=True
    )
    wh_version = models.IntegerField(
        editable=False,
        default=0,
        db_index=True,
    )

    def save( self, *args, **kwargs ):
        # handles here special save behavior...
        return super( WarehouseModel, self ).save( *args, **kwargs )

    objects = WarehouseManager()

class SomeData( WarehouseModel ):
    pid = models.IntegerField( unique=True )

class SomeOtherData( WarehouseModel ):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('pid','chars')
    pid = models.IntegerField()
    chars = models.CharField()
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly for someone who is in need to automate some field-related constraints or other initialization tasks. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

By "dynamically modifying/creating this `unique_together` field", I assume you mean you want to enforce this at the code level, not at the database level.

You can do it in the `save()` method of your model:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if SomeData.objects.filter(name=self.name, version_number=self.version_number).exclude(pk=self.pk).exists():
        raise ValidationError('Such thing exists')

    return super(SomeData, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear with my question. I want the uniqueness to be enforced in conjunction with version_number at the db level. I edited the question to be more explicit

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @Bob's answer you may need to use the `__metaclass__` class as following

```
class ModelBaseMeta(BaseModel):
    
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        ...
    ...

class YourAbstractClass(models.Model, metaclass=ModelBaseMeta):
    
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Instead of putting the `__metaclass__` definition directly inside the abstract class.